# Make a slideshare in order

Tags: vb.net

I made a program where I need a Image auto Slideshare, the problem is that I did it with the 'Random' variable and I want to slide in order like '1, 2, 1, 2 ,1, 2)

Do whatever changes you need.
It's an emergency, thank you.

I have tried doing with a For cycle but as a beginner I don't know that much.

```
Public Class Form4
Private rer As New Random
Dim pos As Integer = 0
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim i As Integer = +1
    PictureBox5.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("boxpu" & rer.Next(i, 3))
End Sub
End Class
```

I want my Auto Slideshare to Slide the pics in order and not randomly.

Comment: Declare a new variable at Form level. Set its value to 1. In `Timer1_Tick` event check if the value of variable is `1` then set it to `2` else set it to `1` and then use it in `GetObject`

Comment: I did not understand taht well, could you shoe me that part in the Timer1_Tick event? Thank you

Comment: I solve it! But i did in other way, i used not visible radio buttons to switch images with a timer, I'm so lucky. Thank you for the help anyways